# Dynamic connection string database c#

Tags: c#, database

im always use this line of code for connection :

```
 string ConnectString = "datasource = mysource; username = myusername; password = mypassword; database = mydatabasename";
```

What im trying to do thistime is instead of writing each time my server data in script directly i want to fill some textbox . so im try to do something like this

```
string ConnectString = "datasource = txtmysource.Text; username = txtmyusername.Text; password = txtmypassword.Text; database = txtmydatabasename.Text";
```

where txtmysource.Text / txtmyusername.Text / txtmypassword.Text / txtmydatabasename.Text are the names of textbox in UI. 
but i can't find the write way to do it.

Answer (score 28):

You probably want `DbConnectionStringBuilder`, ideally the correct one for your RDBMS - so with SQL Server:

```cs
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    UserID = txtmyusername.Text,
    DataSource = txtmysource.Text,
    Password = txtmypassword.Text,
    InitialCatalog = txtmydatabasename.Text,
};
var connectString = builder.ConnectionString;
```

The crucial bit here is that it will apply the correct character escaping etc if (for example) any of the elements contain reserved / non-trivial characters such as whitespace, commas, quotes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with interpolate string like this :

```
string ConnectString = $"datasource = {txtmysource.Text}; username = {txtmyusername.Text}; password = {txtmypassword.Text}; database = {txtmydatabasename.Text}";
```

Comment: which is fine until someone creates a database called `a;b="c` - which yes, is allowed

Comment: Thank you fixed now with your solution

Comment: @RaoufBessghaier you should mark it as the answer (green tick) in that case