# Connect to client's SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a desktop app and I have connected to my SQL Server name.
When I want to install it to client and connect to his SQL Server what should I do if the name of server is different?

Comment: Please share some code of how you are connecting to the SQL Server so that I can advise.

Comment: Store the connection string as a setting in whatever configuration file you use: web.config, app.config, appsettings.json. Change the connection string each time you install the application

Comment: This Q is quite unclear. In anyway, from what I understand you need to change the associate values on your connection string, e.g.  Server Name, DB Name, user, password.

Comment: BTW that's covered in all tutorials and courses. It should be covered in bootcamps or you should ask for your money back (pun intended)

Comment: you could always have a UI to allow them to specify their server? then just build the connection string yourself, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304361/dynamic-connection-string-database-c-sharp/59304396#59304396

Comment: Might be of help: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to store sql server connection string in your configuration file (if you are on .net framework then it's App.Config for desktop apps and Web.Config for web apps) which you can update independently from your compiled app. 
And then you will be able to connect any sql server you have access to.